# Ideal puppet repository for centos 7 distribution

Tags: linux, centos, puppet, centos7, rpm

I am trying do a bit of server management for a dev environment and I wanted to learn about puppet and hence looking at installing puppet on centos 7. Basically, confused as to which version to install and which repository to go with. The

```
https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
```

seems to have puppet 3.8.x

while, the

```
rpm -Uvh https://yum.puppet.com/puppet5/puppet5-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
```

has 5.x and is the recent one. However, the latter is specifically for EL7, not sure if I can use on CentOS 7.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with puppet 5, as mentioned in the latest [docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/puppet_platform.html#enterprise-linux-7).
Note: most of Redhat repos and packages works flawless on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7

Comment: Thanks. I was able to install puppet5